# Is a large backyard fishpond a possible cause of ambient noise?

Tags: noise, noise-reduction

My neighbor has installed an 18-ft fishpond in his backyard.  I am hearing ambient noise in my house, and only in my house, i.e., not right outside my house.  The sound is low-frequency, resonating like a car(s) moving over a steel bridge in the distance.  At various times of the day it sounds more or less intense, sometimes no sound at all. It's heard throughout my house, all floors, and basement.  Could a nearby fishpond installation cause a sound like this?  Maybe it's the fishpond pump?  Apparently there is a mini-waterfall that might also require some kind of motor but I'm not sure.

FYI, this is all information I received from the engineering department of the township whom I contacted when I started hearing the noise.  They say it's possible the noise is coming from the pond, but they don't know.  I thought this site might be a good place to ask as well.

Comment: Can you  ask your neighbor to turn off the devices in his fishpond for a few minutes while you check if the noise stops?

Comment: @Barry I'm not enthusiastic about interacting with, but it seems necessary.  Thanks for the good idea.

Comment: @Barry if by chance the pond was the cause, it might become quite awkward. lol.

Comment: The inference of the vibration of a air-pump with the structure of your house could be the reason. If you do not find the source of the problem, then you have the option to change the house or the furniture somehow. I had the same problem and did not find the source.

Comment: Can you get a mic and some sound analysis software?  When you're talking about a weird sound only you can hear, you'll come off as crazy... [unless you come off as Jonesie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7g6dKncO-I).  Be Jonesie.

Comment: @MikroPower what?  air-pump?  what is an air-pump?  where is it?  you are saying the neighbor's fishpond equipment is effecting my air-pump?  I don't understand.

Comment: low frequency sounds (vibration) resonate true the ground. is the fishpond above our under ground

Comment: @blue_ego - If your neighbour have a big fish pond, then he will have a high power air pump there to provide the fishes with air. They are vibrating and do a lot of noise. If your neighbour do not have decouple the housing of the pump from the ground or especially if he have fixed it to the ground, then the noise can travel very far. Possibly some rubber buffers can solve this problem. I used two separated layers of rubber for my air-pump for the sewage treatment system.

Comment: countermeasure, do you have something in your home that you can put outside and let it vibrate

Comment: @MikroPower thank you for input!  I will find out.

Comment: @Ruskes I don't know. I will find out.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I don't have expensive magma detecting equip. but I have an iphone...lol

Comment: What is you home foundation made off, are the floors elevated or on a ground slab

Comment: @Ruskes the foundation is made from interlocking concrete blocks. the frame is wood.  3-story plus basement

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I am worried too b/c I've asked some other ppl who have entered my house, and they don't hear it, but I absolutely hear it.

Comment: Different people will have different sound sensitives.  Why some stores can play some sounds that will drive teens away, but older people will not be bothered.

Comment: @crip659 haha...I think my neighbors are actually trying to drive me away too...I have another neighbor that has a porchlight with a sensor so the light goes on and off every time anything so much as a squirrel moves...even the wind turns it on...hella annoying.

Comment: loss of hearing starts with high sounds, >>>create a amplifier, use a plastic bottle and cut the bottom leave the top, put in on the floor or wall and listen

Comment: @Ruskes cool, I will try it

Comment: it's not the fishpond!  but i still hear the noise, and only inside the house, not outside...:(

Comment: There are microphone spectrum analyzers app for your smartphone available. Might be worth a try to verify that you indeed hear the noise. Attention: Phone microphones might not be sensible enough in the frequency range you're interested in

Comment: @Martin thx..i'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Is it *possible*? Sure. Is it the source of your noise? As others have said, the easiest test would be to have the neighbor turn it off and see what happens.

However I strongly suggest doing a blind test -- repeated trials where the neighbor flips a coin and either turns it on or off without your knowing which -- and see if it *reliably* matches up. Placebo effect may fool you into thinking you've found the cause when you really haven't.

And if this *is* reliably proven to be the cause, then since it's on their property but bothering you, it would be appropriate to offer to pay some or all of the cost of quieting it. You're asking them a favor that they don't have to agree to; make it easy for them to say yes.